# Data cannot be found in promise axios.all

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Problem is that (this.form.tasks neither other data) cannot be found in the promise then()
 with axios.all. 
Outside the promise it works but not inside. I get the error :

> Uncaught (in promise)  TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of null

```
        axios.all([
            axios.get('/tasks/'+this.token_proj),
            axios.get('/keywords/'+this.token_proj),
            axios.get('/getTasks/'+this.token_proj),
            axios.get(`/discussion/${this.token_proj}/${this.form.page}`)
        ])
        .then(axios.spread(function (tasksResponse, keywordsResponse,getTasksResponse,discResponse) {

            console.log('tasks', tasksResponse.data);
            console.log('keyword', keywordsResponse.data);
            console.log('getrask', getTasksResponse.data);
            console.log('disc', discResponse.data);

            this.form.tasks = tasksResponse.data;



        }));
```

The tasks variable is set in data and exist. I use Vuejs and axios vform.

```
data(){
        return{
            form: new Form({

            tasks:[],
            tasks_management:[],
            discuss:{},
            users:[],
            keywords:[],


            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a variable `const vm = this` before your axios call and use it instead in your callback function `vm.form.tasks = tasksResponse.data`.

Comment: It work perfetly thanks you @HusamIbrahim !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of aliasing `this` consider using the `fat arrow function` to retain the scope of `this` inside of the anonymous callback:

```
.then(axios.spread((tasksResponse, keywordsResponse,getTasksResponse,discResponse) => {
  //this is now scoped correctly.
}))
```